# I am unable to Design the below UI

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, helper

So the problem is I am able to do all the work in the UI Separately but I am not able to place the boxes which reads height and weight and the junction point of the two containers. I tried it using Stack but the layout area of stack changes according to the largest widget in it's children. So I tried making an empty Container then adding the deep blue container on top of it and then tried to position the other two containers at the junction of green and white container but it is not working. It states that the Stack Is of infinite length and couldn't be built. I have Tried Everything Stack, Transform.

So what I want help to design that boxes and place it over there.
And I want it to work for evey device irrespective of size, that is make this complete UI Scrollable or Whatever u all suggest, As I am new to this world
[Here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81hxA.jpg)

Comment: you have to use stack and then use position in  it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do your work like that:
juts copy & paste & understand stack widget.

```
class A extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(

      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[50],
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.loose,
        children: [

        Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          height: height*.3,
          width: width,

          child: Text("Content"),
        ),
          Padding(
            padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top: height*.25),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [

                Card(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    height: 100,
                    width: width*.3,
                  )

                  ,
                ),
                Card(
                  child: Container(height: 100,
                    width: width*.3,
                  )

                  ,
                ),


              ],),
          ),






      ],),

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to use the Stack For this Layout

Or You Have to se the Custom Painter For Drawing the Circle